# .slides.InsertFromFile variable/unknown slide count to insert

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I have an activepresentation defined as myPres and I would like to add slides from a file. I've done some testing with myPres.Slides.InsertFromFile, and I've successfully added slides to my activepresentation. The problem is the powerpoint that I'm wishing to pull from will have a variable amount of slides. It may have 4 slides, It may have 22 slides. How can I modify the below code to say "all slides" from file. Thanks, I'll be happy to provide further clarity as necessary.

```
myPres.slides.InsertFromFile "C:\Users\" & uName & "\productslide.pptx", myPres.slides.Count, 1, 1
```

FYI The last 1 describes how many slides you wish to add from file.

Question answered by DanL below:

```
myPres.slides.InsertFromFile "C:\Users\" & uName & "\productslide.pptx", myPres.slides.Count
```

Comment: Unsure what the arguments mean but perhaps a loop?

Comment: There are three arugments for .slides.InsertFromFile. The first is at what slide in the powerpoint do you want to start inserting from file (i've used myPres.slides.Count meaning I want to add these slides from file to the end of my presentation). The second is "what is the first slide in your file that you want to insert". The third is "what is the last slide in your file that you want to insert". I need to figure out how to make that third argument a variable.

Comment: Wait so `.slides.Count` is what slide you want to start inserting from? Doesn't that give you what you want? Or am I mixing the files? Edit: oh ok. So do a `.slides.Count` on the file you're pulling from?

Comment: I think you're mixing. The .slide.Count I'm using currently is the first argument and is referring to the presentation that I want to add TO. So it says start adding the slides from file at the end of my activepresentation. IE my active presentation has 23 slides, myPres.slides.Count = 23, using that as the first argument tells vba to start adding after the 23rd slide.

Comment: Yea, I edited my comment also see answer below.

Comment: Right i've tried doing .slides.Count as my third argument. Return is a compile error: invalid or unqualified reference. I have a feeling I can't do any sort of measuring on that file as it is not associated to an object.. but that's just a guess

Comment: How can it work for first argument but not third?? How did you qualify it. You need to set the other presentation first as indicated in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply omit the SlideStart and SlideEnd parameters, which are optional. This inserts all the slides from the specified file:

```
myPres.Slides.InsertFromFile "C:\Users\" & uName & "\productslide.pptx", myPres.slides.Count
```

EDIT: I just want to add that the method proposed by findWindow is unnecessarily complex. You don't need to open the origin presentation.

Comment: Hi DanL I amended the code to yours above as it ran successfully and reduced the run time. I didn't realize you could omit the two arguments to the method.. makes me wonder what other unnecessary arguments I'm adding to other things.. Thanks!

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark as answer if it solved your problem :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you set your other presentation to `fromPres` then you can do something like:

```
myPres.slides.InsertFromFile "C:\Users\" & uName & "\productslide.pptx", myPres.slides.Count, 1, fromPres.slides.Count
```

Comment: Hello, I was able to set the fromPres to an object and the use fromPres.slides.count to add all slides. Code used is below. Thanks for your help

Comment: ..I suck at stack overflow commenting

Comment: Uh you can post your code as an answer and check that or check mine. Don't post it as a comment.